# Why I cannot pass a constant to String.Contains() in C++/CLI?

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, parameter-passing, constants

I am observing different behavior in C# and C++/CLI for [System.Contains() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)!

Let's look at C# example,

```
string s1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
string s2 = "fox";
bool b;
b = s1.Contains(s2)
```

As I think the s2 should not be changed, I make it a constant as `const string s2 = "fox";` and the program runs without any problem.

---

Now turns to C++/CLI example,

```
String^ s1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
String^ s2 = "fox";
bool b;
b = s1->Contains( s2 );
```

When I turn s2 to `const String^ s2 = "fox";`, the compilation gives me back error C2664 - cannot convert parameter 1 from `const System::String ^` to `System::String ^`!

---

I know that in C#, one of the three overloaded function is `bool string.Contains(string value)`. It accepts a constant input as the function parameter. Yet in C++/CLI, the function is `bool System::String::Contains(System::String ^ value)`. Both functions look the same to me, but the second one fails my expectation.

Why is that? How can I pass a constant to Contains() in C++/CLI? I program in C++ and C# a lot, but new to C++/CLI.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried typecast to `System::String ^` when passing parameter?

Answer (score 3):

The *const* keyword is C++ specific and only weakly supported in C++/CLI.  You can use it on your own declarations but only the C++/CLI compiler can enforce it.  Neither the CLR nor the .NET Framework classes know anything about it, that would work poorly in other languages, including C#.

Do note that String is already immutable so adding *const* does not get you anything more.  Passing a string literal is certainly supported.

You are possibly getting confused by the different keywords.  C++/CLI has the *initonly* keyword, works the same as *readonly* does in C#.  The C# *const* keyword is *literal* in C++/CLI:

```
public ref class Example{
public:
    literal String^ constantString = "foo";   // Same as const in C#
    initonly String^ readonlyString = "bar";  // Same as readonly in C#
    // etc...
};
```

And works the same way as they do in C#.  A *literal* is directly substituted in the generated code, it can only appear in a class declaration.  Using public literals should be avoided unless they are manifest constants (like Math::Pi).  An *initonly* variable prevents the reference from being modified, not the object itself.  But not an issue with String since it already is immutable.

Comment: Thanks i did the same error. In my case, it was a problem after to pass the content to another function except by copying the value in another string.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that in C#, one of the three overloaded function is  bool string.Contains(string value). It accepts a constant input as the function parameter

No, it accepts a reference to a string object. It says nothing about "constant" in the contract.

The CLR does not support const in the C++ sense. (Because most .NET languages don't, and the CLR has to stick to a common subset that can be expressed in all the languages that are built on top of it).

All functions in the class library are defined without specifying constness, and so your C++ (or C++/CLI) code has to throw away the const as well. The function takes a managed reference to a string -- and not a managed reference to a *const* string. Because that's just how CLR functions are defined.

Answer (score 0):

When you add `const` to some variable, you add some restriction. It is common to mark function parameter `const` if you not planning to modify it. You cannot, however, pass argument with more restrictions where less restrictions is expected. I think that, it this particular case, `const` is omitted maybe by pure mistake.

If you typecast parameter to `System::String ^`, this should solve your problem.